# Parse Erb File for Method Parameter with regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am trying to parse an erb file for the parameter of the method getMetaValueForName() like this:

```
File.open(tpath) do |file|
    while (line = file.gets)
        name = line.match(/getMetaValueForName\(".*"\)/).to_s
        name = name.match(/"(.*?)"/).to_s
        netaName = name.gsub!(/"/, '')
        meta_names.push(name) unless name.blank?
    end
end
```

This works fine unless there are multiple getMetaValueForName() in one line, then I get only the value of the first method.

So i tried to change the regex to:

```
name = line.match(/(getMetaValueForName\(".*?"\))/)
```

and then get the results with changing the name variable to an array and do the other match and gsub in an each do block.

But I still only get the first result and not all of them…

Or is there a easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the String.scan [method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001181) to retrieve an array with matches of the pattern inside the string.

Also, create a group inside your regexp to get the value directly - the matches will be arrays, and your first group will be the first element of that array.

Here's some example code (untested):

```
IO.foreach(tpath) do |line|
  metanames += line.scan(/getMetaValueForName\("(.*)"\)/).map {|match| match[0] }
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This works! Except that i have to use the newer regex /(getMetaValueForName\(".*?"\))/